# ISO date string to google.protobuf.Timestamp?

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers, isodate, android-jetpack-datastore

I have an ISO date string like this:

```
2023-06-13T19:34:35.12345Z
```

and I need to convert it to an `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` to store it in a [Proto DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#proto-datastore).

How can I do that? (I am using Kotlin on Android)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are likely looking for [`Timestamps.parse`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/java/api-docs/com/google/protobuf/util/Timestamps.html#parse-java.lang.String-).